# cannot write video in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a project which involves object detection, it created bounding boxes around an object and i want save the video.
What i have tried :

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/content/gdrive/My Drive/cam_output_final.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v'), 30, (288, 1024))

fr_num = 0

while True:

    ret1, frame1 = shortCap.read()
    ret2, frame2 = longCap.read()

    r1, image1 = make_detections(frame1, mRcnn)
    frame1_final, pep_cnt1 = visualize_results(image1, r1)

    r2, image2 = make_detections(frame2, mRcnn)
    frame2_final, pep_cnt2 = visualize_results(image2, r2)
    
    cv2.putText(frame1_final, 'Number of people: {}'.format(str(pep_cnt1)),
        (50, 260), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 1)

    cv2.putText(frame2_final, 'Number of people: {}'.format(str(pep_cnt2)),
        (50, 260), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 1)

    print(frame1_final.shape) # shape = (288, 512, 3)
    print(frame2_final.shape) # shape = (288, 512, 3)

    both = np.concatenate((frame1_final, frame2_final), axis=1)

    print(both.shape) # shape = (288, 1024, 3)
    print(fr_num)

    out.write(both)

    fr_num += 1

    if fr_num > 5:
        break

cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried everything but it is no saving at all!.
Everytime a cam_output.avi file gets saved of size 5.55K! and it doesn't work!

Comment: make sure your application has access to opencv_ffmpeg dll file. Test it by writing "MJPG" videos. If you want to save mp4 files, you'll have to choose a .mp4 extension for the filename.

Comment: @Micka not working!

Comment: `frame.shape` shows size `(height, width)` - `(288, 1024)` - but `VideoWriter` needs size `(width, height)` - it means `(1024, 288)`

Answer (score 1):

`frame.shape` shows size `(height, width)` - it means `(288, 1024)` - but `VideoWriter` needs size `(width, height)` - it means `(1024, 288)`

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(..., (1024, 288))
```